# Duplication with Chunks in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, performance, spring-batch

I have a huge file, I need to read it and dump it into DB. **Any invalid records(invalid length, duplicate keys, etc), if present need to be written into a Error Report**. Due to the huge size of the file we tried using the chunk-size(commit-interval) as 1000/5000/10000. In the process I found that the data was being processed redundantly due to the usage of chunks and thus my Error Report is incorrect, it not only has the actual invalid records from the input-file but also the duplicates from the chunks.

Code snippet:

```
@Bean
public Step readAndWriteStudentInfo() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("readAndWriteStudentInfo")
            .<Student, Student>chunk(5000).reader(studentFileReader()).faultTolerant()
            .skipPolicy(skipper)..listener(listener).processor(new ItemProcessor<Student, Student>() {


                @Override
                public Student process(Student Student) throws Exception {
                    if(processedRecords.contains(Student)){
                        return null;
                    }else {
                        processedRecords.add(Student);
                        return Student;
                    }
                }
    }).writer(studentDBWriter()).build();
}


@Bean
public ItemReader<Student> studentFileReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Student> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(studentInfoFileName));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Student>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new FixedLengthTokenizer() {
                {
                    setNames(classProperties50);
                    setColumns(range50);
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Student>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(Student.class);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    reader.setSaveState(false);
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new TrailerSkipper());
    return reader;

}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Student> studentDBWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Student> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    writer.setSql(insertQuery);
    writer.setDataSource(datSource);
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Student>());
    return writer;
}
```

I've tried with various chunk sizes, 10, 100, 1000, 5000. The accuracy of my error report deteriorates with the increase in chunk size. Writing to Error Report is happening from my implementation of Skip Policy, kindly do let me know if that code is required too to help me out.

How do I ensure that my writer picks up unique set of records in each chunk?

Skipper Implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable t, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
    String exception = t.getClass().getSimpleName();
    if (t instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (exception) {
    case "FlatFileParseException":
        FlatFileParseException ffpe = (FlatFileParseException) t;
        String errorMessage = "Line no = " + ffpe.getLineNumber() + "  " + ffpe.getMessage() + "  Record is ["
                + ffpe.getInput() + "].\n";
        writeToRecon(errorMessage);
        return true;
    case "SQLException":
        SQLException sE = (SQLException) t;
        String sqlErrorMessage = sE.getErrorCode() + " Record is [" + sE.getCause() + "].\n";
        writeToRecon(sqlErrorMessage);
        return true;
    case "BatchUpdateException":
        BatchUpdateException batchUpdateException = (BatchUpdateException) t;
        String btchUpdtExceptionMsg = batchUpdateException.getMessage() + " " + batchUpdateException.getCause();
        writeToRecon(btchUpdtExceptionMsg);
        return true;
```

default:
            return false;
        }

Comment: Please provide the configuration for `skipper`.

Comment: Hello Michael, I've added skipper code. There's no configuration, I've not registered it as a bean.

Comment: Why are you using a `SkipPolicy` implementation to log that instead of a `SkipListener`?

Comment: callbacks method from SkipListener are never getting invoked. i have just pust loggers, but I never see them getting logged.

Comment: Did you register the skip listener?

Comment: I have tried in both the ways, registering the implementation of Listener as a componnet and Autowiring in my Batch. And providing an anonymous implementation, none of it invokes OnSkip* methods. Nothing is getting logged.

Comment: added the code for Listener.

Comment: It's working now thanks! I was registering in a wrong way.

Comment: Still My recon report is invalid, it has written lot of valid records too, as in the problem statement